# Clickable rows in seperate HTML file to open different links in a new tab

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery and got several rows in a table located in a separate HTML file.
Each row is redirecting to a local HTML file **successfully** when clicked on. (using window.location)

**What I am trying to achieve**

What I would like to accomplish instead is when I click the row the local HTML file is **opening in a new tab** and not the current one.

I am aware this would be considered easy to achieve if this was an `<a>` anchor.

**My problem**

`window.open` does not work in this specific case (at least the way I tried it) and applying `target="_blank"` would be useless as this is not an `<a>` tag. It's a table row.

**What I've tried**

jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
  window.open = $(this).data("href");
  });
});
```

Seperate HTML file:

```
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>thead1</th>
        <th>thead2</th>
        <th>thead3</th>
        <th>thead4</th>
        <th>thead5</th>
        <th>thead6</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="\path\index.html">
        <td>tcell1</td>
        <td>tcell2</td>
        <td>tcell3</td>
        <td>tcell4</td>
        <td>tcell5</td>
        <td>tcell6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="clickable-row" data-href="\path\differentindex.html">
        <td>tcell1</td>
        <td>tcell2</td>
        <td>tcell3</td>
        <td>tcell4</td>
        <td>tcell5</td>
        <td>tcell6</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

*To get an overview of my DOM structure I am referring to the separate HTML file with an includeHTML function.*

**Sources I've read**

I'm assuming I cannot use `window.open` the way I've tried after reading up on how the [object works](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp).

And I've read the difference between .open and .location [here](https://www.phpflow.com/jquery/difference-between-window-open-and-window-location-href/). However, I am not quite sure when to use what.

Comment: might be able to get some ideas from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Comment: can you try to put the html directly in the parent file and not included as a separate one?

Comment: @Pete I tried what you suggested at first, but that just opens `link/[object%20Object]`. Every solution in the link you've provided assumes you got an anchor tag and not a table row which is my case.

Comment: @LelioFaieta My table is huge and constantly expanding. Pasting my tables into the main HTML instead would make it really difficult to navigate and is not what I want at all.

Comment: you can try by adding just a few lines and see if the `name='_blank'` attribute works in that case. It's just for testing your issue.

Comment: @Sanguinary one of the options in the answers was to create an anchor when the click was done and then do a click on the created anchor (it doesn't have to be added to the dom) - see the bottom of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript#answer-28374344

Comment: @Pete This seems to work if I only got 1 static link. Correct me if I am wrong, but would it even work for table rows with several different links?

Comment: I don't see why not - you would just need to create a new link for each row

Comment: @Pete Would that be the most efficient way if I e.g got 100 rows?

Comment: I would rethink what you are trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
           window.open($(this).data("href"),'_blank');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
window.open(
  'your url',
  '_blank' // <- This is what makes it open in a new window.
);
```

Or you can create anchor tag and make click event

```
$("body").append('<a id="link" href="your url" target="blank">&nbsp;</a>');
```

$('#link')[0].click();

```
$( ".clickable-row" ).each(function(index) {
$(this).on("click", function(){
   window.open($(this).data("href"),'_blank'); 
});});
```

Comment: Already tried and did not seem to work. And link is not the same. Each row has a different link.

Comment: Mentioning once again that my link is not static. Using `href="your_url"` would work if I only had 1 link. But I got several.

Comment: i have used your code in plunker and it works fine, please see https://jsfiddle.net/fkwhvvhk/124/

Comment: This does not work for me. It will not respond and nothing happens. Can this be due to me having it in a seperate HTML file?

Comment: You have to write loop logic in jquery please refer edited answer, may it works

Comment: Appreciate your help! However unfortunaterly once again, this did not work. Are you sure `target="_blank"` can be applied to table rows?

Comment: yes and also it works in the plunker example, will you please tell me what happen to your screen or else please check your console is there any error?